# TTY input queue too slow to return data

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, tty

I've recently noticed a very odd behavior on my system (running on an AT91SAM9G15): Despite the fact I'm reading serial port continuously, TTY driver takes sometimes 1,2s to deliver data from the input queue.
Thing is: I'm not losing any data, it just takes too many calls to read for it to come.

Maybe my code will help to explain the problem.

First off, I set my serial port:

```
/* 8N1 */
tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;
/** Parity bit (none) */
tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
/** Stop bit (1)*/
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
/* Noncanonical mode */
tty.c_lflag = 0;
tty.c_oflag = 0;
tty.c_cc[VMIN] =  0;
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

Later on, select is called:

```
s_ret = select(rfid_fd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &port_timeval);
```

So read() can do its magic:

```
...
 if ((rd_ret = read(rfid_fd, &recv_buff[u16_recv_len], (u16_req_len - u16_recv_len))) > 0)
...
```

Right afterwards, if I keep reading serial port for 15s for example, for several times I can see no data coming and that data, which I know arrived on time (it's timestamped), comes late. Delays in fetching data from input queue may vary from 300ms to 1,5s.

I've tried every kind of setting I could think of. It's tricky now since I don't know if at91 UART drivers aren't delivering data to tty driver or tty driver isn't fetching it? Which is which here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Maybe my code will help to explain the problem"* -- No, those tiny code fragments are not sufficient.  And what you do show could be incomplete for an operational serial terminal. See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Comment: Why do you think setting `c_lflag = 0;`  will put the terminal y raw mode.  Are you sure of this?  No other flags (probably implementation dependent) are getting in the middle? sure?  Why not `tcgetattr() -> mask flags -> tcsetattr()` as it is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: By the way, setting both VMIN and VTIME to 0 makes you consume cpu at full speed, as you only get input when it's available.  It should be better VMIN <- 1, VTIME <- 0.  This way you get blocked until one char arrives to the port.

Answer (score 0):

The normal procedure to set port flags is to read the `termios` structure, save it for later restoring, modify (in a copy of it) the flags you want to change, and do a `tcsetattr()` call.  You have initialised `c_lflag = 0;` which can have some secondary effects related to your problem.

The next thing you have to consider is reading the documentation about `VMIN` and `VTIME` elements.  Setting both to `0` makes the driver a non blocking device, so you'll get in a loop trying to read whatever should be in the buffer.  But before doing that, think twice that you have two threads competing for putting the characters in the buffer (your process, trying to get it from the buffer and the driver interrupt routine, that tries to put the character just read) without rest.  It should be better (and probably here is the problem) to wait for one character to be available, setting `VMIN` to `1` and `VTIME` to `0`.  This makes the driver to awake your process as soon as one character is available, and probably nearer to what you want.

After all this amount of guesses, you haven't post any reproducible code that can be used to check what you say, so this is the most we can do to help you.